# table of contents in two column different layout

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I would like to get the below output in my `table of contents`. How do achieve this.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \if@cfthaschapter
      \vskip \cftbeforesecskip
    \else
      \addpenalty\@secpenalty
      \addvspace{\cftbeforesecskip}
    \fi
    {\leftskip \cftsecindent\relax
     \rightskip \@tocrmarg
     \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent \cftsecindent\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima \cftsecnumwidth\relax
     \let\@cftbsnum \cftsecpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum \cftsecaftersnum
     \let\@cftasnumb \cftsecaftersnumb
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {\cftsecfont #1}\nobreak
     \cftsecfillnum{#2}}%
  \fi}
\if@cfthaschapter
  \setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{\z@ \@plus.2\p@}
  \setlength{\cftsecindent}{2em}
  \setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.3em}
\else
  \setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{1.0em \@plus\p@}
  \setlength{\cftsecindent}{0em}
  \setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{1.5em}
\fi


\renewcommand*{\l@subsection}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\@ne
    \vskip \cftbeforesubsecskip
    {\leftskip \cftsubsecindent\relax
     \rightskip \@tocrmarg
     \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent \cftsubsecindent\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima \cftsubsecnumwidth\relax
     \let\@cftbsnum \cftsubsecpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum \cftsubsecaftersnum
     \let\@cftasnumb \cftsubsecaftersnumb
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {\hspace*{-12pt}\cftsubsecfont #1}\nobreak
     \cftsubsecfillnum{#2}}%
  \fi}
\if@cfthaschapter
  \setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{5.5em}
  \setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3.2em}
\else
  \setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{1.5em}
  \setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{2.3em}
\fi
\parskip .5ex                       % Add space between Contents items
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Contents}
\markboth{Contents}{Contents}

\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {6}Decimals}{00}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6A}Decimals and place value}{00}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6B}Rounding decimals}{00}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6C}Addition and subtraction}{00}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6D}Multiplying and dividing by powers of 10}{00}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6E}Multiplication of decimals}{00}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6F}Division of decimals}{00}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6G}Decimals and fractions}{00}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {6H}Decimals and percentages}{00}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {}Investigation}{00}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {}Review: Chapter summary}{00}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {}\qquad Multiple-choice questions}{00}

\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}Measurement and Geometry}{}
    \contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Counting}{}
     \contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}Numeration}{}
     \contentsline {section}{\numberline {6}Fractions}{}
     \contentsline {section}{\numberline {7}Calculation}{}
     \contentsline {section}{\numberline {8}Number patterns}{}
     \contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}Place value}{}
     \contentsline {section}{\numberline {4}Addition and subtraction}{}                                        
     \contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}Place value}{}         
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the rationale behind the two columns? They seem to both represent `chapter`s and `section`s... but why the different formatting?

Comment: @Werner: `chapters` and `sections` are one column and some `verbatim` contents is second column.

Comment: Do you really need to use the toc to write the "verbatim contents"?  You can use \label and \pageref together with the paracol package instead.

Comment: After further testing, the book version of the table of contents has to be on a page by itself, so no parallel columns.  Frankly, it would be easier to write your own toc.

Comment: @john: could you please give sample code for further testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some experiments using paracol:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}

\newcommand{\comment}[1]% #1 = text and expandable macros
{\switchcolumn*\vspace{-\baselineskip}#1\switchcolumn}

\newcommand{\commentline}[2]% #1 = text, #2 = \thepage
{\switchcolumn*\vspace{-\baselineskip}#1 \dotfill\makebox[2.25em]{#2}\switchcolumn}

\begin{document}%
\begin{paracol}{2}%
\tableofcontents
\end{paracol}

\chapter{First Chapter}%
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\comment{test 1}}

\section{First Section}
\addtocontents{toc}{\string\commentline{test 2}{\thepage}}
\end{document}
```

[image: test]