# custom table of contents using tikz and tocloft

Tags: tikz-pgf, tocloft, paracol

I have using `tocloft` and `tikz` for creating custom `table of contents`. Please find the my MWE below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft,refcount}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{rulecolor}{cmyk}{0,1,0.29,0}
\newcommand{\tocchpnumfont}{\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont\color{chapternumcolor}}
\newcommand{\tocchptextfont}{\fontsize{11}{14}\selectfont\color{white}}
\definecolor{chapternumcolor}{cmyk}{0.40,1,0,0}

\makeatletter
% redefinitions for part entries
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}

\renewcommand*{\l@part}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \cftpartbreak
    \begingroup
      {\interlinepenalty\@M
       \leavevmode
       \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\cftpartfont\cftpartname}%
       \addtolength{\@tempdima}{\cftpartnumwidth}%
       \let\@cftbsnum \cftpartpresnum
       \let\@cftasnum \cftpartaftersnum
       \let\@cftasnumb \cftpartaftersnumb
       \advance\memRTLleftskip\@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip     -\memRTLleftskip
       }
      \nobreak
        \global\@nobreaktrue
        \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\newcommand\chapternumberline[1]    {\mbox{\Large\@chapapp~#1}\par\noindent}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0pt}{0pt}
\newcommand\cftchapterpagefont{\tocchpnumfont}

\newcommand*{\l@mychap}[3]{%
  \def\@chapapp{#3}\vskip1ex%
  \par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
  \parbox{4.7em}{%
    \hfill{\cftchapterpagefont #2}%
  }\hspace*{1.5em}%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.7em-15pt\relax}{%
    \tocchptextfont #1%
  }%
  \end{minipage}\par\vspace{2ex}%
}

\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{}%
}

\newcommand*{\l@appendix}[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\appendixname}%
}

\newcommand\cftsectionfont{\sffamily}
\newcommand\cftsectionpagefont{\hfill\color{myred}}
\newcommand{\cftsectionleader}{\nobreak}
\newcommand{\cftsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\cftsetindents{section}{9.5em}{2.5em}
\newcommand\cftsectionformatpnum[1]{%
  \hskip1em\hbox to 4em{{\cftsectionpagefont #1\hfill}}}

\newcommand\cftsubsectionfont{\sffamily}
\newcommand\cftsubsectionpagefont{\hfill\color{myred}}
\newcommand\cftsubsectionleader{\nobreak}
\newcommand{\cftsubsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\newcommand\cftsubsectiondotsep{\cftnodots}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{10.5em}{3em}
\newcommand\cftsubsectionformatpnum[1]{%
  \hskip1em\hbox to 4em{{\cftsubsectionpagefont #1\hfill}}}
\makeatother

\newlength\Myhead
\setlength\Myhead{\dimexpr\headheight+\headsep+1in+\voffset+5ex\relax}

\newlength\Myfoot
\setlength\Myfoot{\dimexpr\paperheight-\Myhead-\textheight-\footskip+5ex\relax}

\newcounter{chapmark}

\newcommand\StartMark{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\label{st\thechapmark}%
    \protect\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]   
    \protect\node [anchor=base] (s\thechapmark) {};%
    \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{st\thechapmark}=\getpagerefnumber{en\thechapmark}     \else
    \protect\draw[myyellow,line width=3pt] let \protect\p3=     (s\thechapmark),%
      \protect\p4 = (current page.south) in %
      ($ (4em,\protect\y3) + (0,-1ex) $) -- ($ (4em,\protect\y4) + (0,    \protect\the\Myfoot)$);\fi
    \protect\end{tikzpicture}\par}%
}

\newcommand\EndMark{
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\label{en\thechapmark}%
  \protect\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]   
  \protect\node [anchor=base] (e\thechapmark) {};
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{st\thechapmark}=\getpagerefnumber{en\thechapmark} 
  \protect\draw[myyellow,line width=1pt] let \protect\p1=     (s\thechapmark), \protect\p2=(e\thechapmark) in ($ (4em,\protect\y1) +     (0,-1ex) $) -- ($ (4em,\protect\y2) + (0,2ex) $);
  \else%
  \protect\draw[myyellow,line width=1pt] let \protect\p1=     (e\thechapmark), \protect\p2=(current page.north) in ($(4em,\protect\y2) +     (0,-\protect\the\Myhead)$) -- ($ (4em,\protect\y1) + (0,1.5ex) $);
\fi
\protect\end{tikzpicture}}\stepcounter{chapmark}%
}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}

\begin{document}

\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {}Negative numbers}{8}    {chapter.1}
\StartMark
\label {st0}\begin {tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node     [anchor=base] (s0) {};\end {tikzpicture}\par 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8A}Integers}{00}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8B}Adding and subtracting positive     integers }{00}{section.1.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8C}Adding and subtracting negative     integers}{00}{section1.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8D}Multiplication and division of     integers}{00}{section.1.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8E}Order of operation}{00}    {section*.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8F}Substituting integers}{00}    {section*.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8G}The number plane}{00}    {section.1.4}
\contentsline {section}{Investigation}{00}{section.1.5}
\contentsline {section}{Review: Chapter summary}{00}{section.1.6}
\contentsline {subsection}{Multiple-choice questions}{00}{subsection.1.6}
\contentsline {subsection}{Short-answer questions}{00}{subsection.1.6}
\contentsline {subsection}{Extended response questions}{00}    {subsection.1.6}
\label {en0}\begin {tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node     [anchor=base] (e0) {}; \draw [rulecolor,line width=1pt] let \p 1= (s0), \p     2=(e0) in ($ (7em,\y 1) + (0,1ex) $) -- ($ (7em,\y 2) + (0,2.24ex) $); \end     {tikzpicture} 
\EndMark

\contentsline {section}{1 Counting}{}{}
\contentsline {section}{2 Numeration}{}{}
\contentsline {section}{3 fractions}{}{}
\contentsline {section}{7 Calculation}{}{}
\contentsline {section}{8 Number patterns}{}{}
\contentsline {section}{3 Place value}{}{}
\contentsline {section}{4 Addition and subtraction}{}{}


\end{document}
```

I would like to expect the output are :

I have used [table of contents in two column different layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217607/table-of-contents-in-two-column-different-layout/217770#217770) tried to use `paracol` package and unable to get the correct output. So that i have moved to `tikz` and still not got expected output.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the table of contents on the right is? Are they chapters? I can't find any link between the two tables of contents. The numbers next to the chapters also seem random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task is in the form: there is given input (the set of `\contentsline`s) and we need to create macros for reading this input and for creating desired output. I show typical plain TeX solution. You can see that the code is compact and simple. Only, what you need, is to know the `\hbox` / `\vbox` arithmetic at TeX primitive level. No external packages are needed (only one external file for loading TeXgyre Heros Narrow font is used).

You can try to insert this macro to your LaTeX code, but you need change the first line to the LaTeX command for loading the Helvetica or Heros Narrow font.

```
\input cs-heros \narrow % this is plain TEX specific, replace this if you needed

\def\dimA{80mm}
\def\dimB{7mm}
\def\dimC{12mm}
\def\dimD{10mm}
\def\dimE{.8pt}
\def\dimF{2mm}
\def\dimG{65mm}
\def\dimH{45mm}

\def\Magenta {\pdfliteral{0 .9 .1 .3 K 0 1 .2 .3 k}}
\def\Black   {\pdfliteral{0 g 0 G}}
\def\White   {\pdfliteral{1 g 1 G}}
\def\Blue    {\pdfliteral{1 .3 0 .3 k}}
\def\LightBlue {\pdfliteral{.2 .16 0 .12 k}}

\def\contentsline #1{\csname TOC#1\endcsname}
\def\TOCchapter #1#2#3{%
   \hbox to\dimA{\bf\llap{\Magenta#2\Black\kern\dimF}\rlap{\chaprule\hss}%
                 \kern\dimF\White #1\hss 00\Black\kern\dimB}
   \nointerlineskip\baselineskip=0pt
   \hbox{\kern\dimD \Magenta\vrule height1ex width\dimE}\nointerlineskip
}
\def\TOCsection #1#2#3{\hbox to\dimA{\kern\dimD\secrule #1\hss #2\kern\dimB}}
\def\TOCsubsection #1#2#3{\hbox to\dimA{\kern\dimD\secrule \kern\dimC #1\hss #2\kern\dimB}}

\def\TOCchapterA #1#2#3{\hbox to\dimA{\bf\rlap{\chaprule\hss}
                                       \kern\dimF\Magenta #1\hss}\medskip}
\def\TOCsectionA #1#2#3{\hbox{\kern\dimF\tocstrut#1}\hrule width\dimH}

\def\secrule {\Magenta\vrule height2.1ex depth.6ex width\dimE\Black\kern2mm}
\def\chaprule{\Blue\vrule height2.3ex depth.7ex width\dimA\Black} 
\def\tocstrut{\vrule height2.3ex depth.7ex width0pt}
\def\chapternumberline{}
\def\numberline#1{\hbox to0pt{\hss#1\kern4mm}}
\def\StartContents{\hbox\bgroup \offinterlineskip \vtop\bgroup}
\def\StartMark{}
\def\EndMark{\egroup\kern2mm\vtop\bgroup
   \let\TOCchapter=\TOCchapterA \let\dimA=\dimG  \let\TOCsection=\TOCsectionA 
   \let\Blue=\LightBlue}
\def\EndContents{\Black\egroup\egroup}


\StartContents
\contentsline {chapter}{\chapternumberline {}Negative numbers}{8} {chapter.1}
\StartMark
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8A}Integers}{00}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8B}Adding and subtracting positive integers }{00}{section.1
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8C}Adding and subtracting negative integers}{00}{section1.3
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8D}Multiplication and division of integers}{00}{section.1.3
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8E}Order of operation}{00} {section*.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8F}Substituting integers}{00} {section*.3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {8G}The number plane}{00} {section.1.4}
\contentsline {section}{Investigation}{00}{section.1.5}
\contentsline {section}{Review: Chapter summary}{00}{section.1.6}
\contentsline {subsection}{Multiple-choice questions}{00}{subsection.1.6}
\contentsline {subsection}{Short-answer questions}{00}{subsection.1.6}
\contentsline {subsection}{Extended response questions}{00} {subsection.1.6}
\EndMark
\contentsline {chapter}{Statistic and Probability}{} {}
\contentsline {section}{1 Counting}{}{}
\contentsline {section}{2 Numeration}{}{}
\contentsline {section}{3 Fractions}{}{}
\contentsline {section}{7 Calculation}{}{}
\contentsline {section}{8 Number patterns}{}{}
\contentsline {section}{3 Place value}{}{}
\contentsline {section}{4 Addition and subtraction}{}{}
\EndContents

\end
```

The result:
[image: toc]

Comment: In `Plain TeX` it's working fine.